# Sending data to an offline/inactive app

Tags: android, ios, ios7, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to create a mobile chat/message application. There will be online and offline users. I want users to be able to send messages to online AND offline users.If two users are online I will use websockets for them to talk, but I am running into problems if an online user wants to send an offline user a message. If an online user sends an offline user a message I would like the sender to know if the message was delivered or not. Is this possible? I know I can use push notifications to send the offline user that a new message has arrived, but I can't find anything about sending the message to the offline user while the app is still not running. Do I have to store the message in a database and then when the receiver opens his app send them the new message or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much yes. All of your messages should be stored in a database, depending on the complexity of the rest of your system I would recommend some sort of schema-less, no-SQL database. The client devices should open a persistent socket to the server when it opens and messages get pushed down the pipe from the server. If the server receives a message to send to a client that is offline, send a push notification to the  relevant device. The first thing you should do when a client connects is look in the database for any messages that have not been sent to the user and push them down the socket.

Let me know if you need any clarification.